# Set flag if reference exist in other table

Tags: sqlite

I would like to set the column `active` to 1 if there is a row in table register pointing to the corresponding module table. Unfortunately `m.id` is not visible in the `SELECT EXISTS` query.

```
SELECT *, active
    FROM module m
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 FROM register r WHERE m.id = r.module_id LIMIT 1
        ) AS aktive
    );
```

**test.db**

```
CREATE TABLE module (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    tag TEXT
);

INSERT INTO module (tag) VALUES ("Module A");
INSERT INTO module (tag) VALUES ("Module B");

CREATE TABLE register (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    module_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO register (module_id) VALUES (2);

SELECT * from module;
SELECT * from register;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, (SELECT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 FROM register r WHERE m.id = r.module_id LIMIT 1
        ) ) AS active
    FROM module m;
```